# How to make an info about prefix on discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

**I've made a code for my bot to change his prefix, but i can't make a command, that shows info about his prefix. Can you help me? I've tried to make it, but it isn't working.**

Code:

````
@client.command()
async def infoprefix(ctx, new : str):
    await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
        title = 'Prefix',
        description = (f'Prefix now: ```{new}```'),
        colour = discord.Color.blue()
    ))
````

Comment: Welcome to Stack! Would you mind showing your code to change the prefix?

Comment: I have done it by storing the prefix in a config/json file and then retrieving it from there.

Comment: Maybe this video will help you out https://youtu.be/yrHbGhem6I4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

acording to [official docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=prefix#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_prefix) you should make it that way:

````py
@client.command()
async def infoprefix(ctx):
    new = await bot.get_prefix(ctx)
    await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
        title = 'Prefix',
        description = (f'Prefix now: ```{new}```'),
        colour = discord.Color.blue()
        ))
````

for further coding - reply to answer cuz its yet 100% unsure ;)

Comment: thx, it's working!

Comment: yep. i also already tested ;)